# Travel to Denmark

Tags: trains, germany, covid-19, denmark, albanian-citizens

Can I travel to Denmark from Germany by train. I am an Albanian citizen.
Does the border have control for COVID 19 test results or something else.

I will go to my sister home to open the house because shes not in Denmark this time. Because I read on internet and Denmark is closed for everyone but train still works.
I ask Is there border control or test control at the Germany-Denmark border? Do you have any information for these?

Comment: Without knowing the current, exact rules, the answer will depend on why you are travelling to Denmark and where you live in Germany. Entry for the purpose of tourism is not allowed for residents of all states expect Schleswig-Holstein. The answer might even depend on where exactly you are going in Denmark.

Comment: I dont stay in germany i will go transit from Germany

Comment: In which case you question is even more unclear and entirely impossible to answer. You will then also be subject to any restrictions in place in Germany.

Comment: Can you answer have control on train from germany to denmark? Is simple

Comment: I do not know but I fear you will not be able to travel through Germany and Denmark. Even if there is no check at the actual border, you can be checked everywhere in Germany and Denmark and it is likely that you will not be allowed to make this travel.

Comment: @Liku There are only selective border checks when entering Denmark from Germany by train, so there's a good chance of you slipping through. If checked, you can claim you're continuing by train to Sweden, which is allowed with zero restrictions

Comment: @Crazydre, lying on the record is a **really** bad suggestion. These kinds of lies tend to come back and bite.

Comment: @Crazydre, It is against TSE politics to tell people to break the law.

Comment: @o.m. What record? These things aren't recorded

Comment: @Crazydre, quarantine regulations are terribly in flux. Also, see the comment by Willeke.

Comment: The trains are running for those who are allowed to enter Denmark. One of the exceptions allowed is to visit a near relative (sister), but since your sister is not there this would not apply to you.

Comment: https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/DNK/7001

Comment: @o.m. This specific thing is **not** "in flux". Denmark has consistently allowed all transit with zero restrictions since June and has no intention to suddenly change that.

Comment: @Crazydre, Denmark issued new restrictions on Jutland districts as of 19th November. Today is the 27th. I see the whole travel situation "in flux." And see this about German use of tracing data during corona: https://netzpolitik.org/2020/bayern-polizei-nutzt-corona-kontaktlisten-fuer-drogenermittlungen/

Comment: @o.m. OP doesn't need to supply contact data to German authorities since they're only transiting https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/merkblatt-dea.html

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, you will *transit* Germany. Germany will require you to fill an [online entry record](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende.html), alternatively a paper one. What you write there should be the truth, for practical and ethical reasons.

Comment: The German Federal Police has confirmed to me that the entry form is **not** required for transit travellers not staying overnight at an address (asked this as I'm soon taking the train CH -> DE -> DK -> SE)

Comment: @Crazydre Be aware that transport operators are often not aware of the details and may require you to submit an entry form even if you are not required or even able to do so. I was planning to take the Stena Line ferry from Gothernburg to Kiel and they require when checking in for the ferry that all passengers show that they have submitted the form. Coming from a non-risk area, I am neither required nor able to fill out the form and would probably be denied transport.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thanks for the input. I'll message my TIMATIC contact and have him ensure the database is updated to say the form isn't required for passengers in transit (incl. air -> overland)

Comment: @Crazydre I was not 100% sure, but I have now checked at least the Bavarian regulation (note that the requirement to fill out the entry form is mandated in state law, not in federal law, and may vary from state to state). There is in Bavaria no exception from the requirement to fill out the entry form if you are just transiting. If transiting Bavaria, you are exempt from the quarantine requirements, but not from submitting the entry form. Which btw is quite difficult, since you have to provide information about where you are staying the next 10 days (in Germany) to submit the form.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo You say it's not regulated federally. Yet the Bundespolizei told me this without me having specified my route. And as you said it makes sense due to the lack of an address. Strange! I've now asked DB Sicherheit to make a note of this in my DB booking to avoid me being wrongfully denied boarding

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Just found this, so it **is** federal https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/merkblatt-dea.html

Comment: @Crazydre It is confusing, but the problem is that in Germany, public health lies within the jurisdiction of the states and federal authorities are not allowed to mandate many of the measurements which have been imposed recently. This has led to confusing rules varying from state to state and most states have recently agreed upon accepting 'recommendations' from federal authorities and implementing them in state law. This has led to at least similar rules across Germany, but details still vary from state to state.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The form is an *entry* requirement though, not merely a matter of state quarantine law, so it's only logical for it to be federally regulated

Comment: @Crazydre German law is not logical. It is indeed the entry into a state and not the entry into Germany as a federal subject, which legally triggers these requirements. The introduction of the relevant regulations in Bavaria and Baden-Württemberg translate as follows: "Persons who are entering the Free State of Bavaria and have within ten days before entry staid in a risk area ..." and "Persons who by land, sea or air enter the State of Baden-Württemberg from abroad and at any point of time within the last ten days before entry have staid in an area, which ...".

Comment: @Crazydre The **digitalen Einreisemeldung** is based (as was the **Aussteigekarte** before it) on Federal law (Drittes Gesetz zum Schutz der Bevölkerung bei einer epidemischen Lage von nationaler Tragweite). The state Ordinances (Rechtsverordnungen) are **authorized** by [§ 32 Infektionsschutzgesetzes (IfSG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ifsg/__32.html), which is a federal law, to implement further needed measures not otherwise dealt with on the federal level.

Comment: @Crazydre The quoted Baden-Württemberg 'law' (which is a an Ordinance) makes this clear since ut starts with: *On the basis of Section 32 in conjunction with Sections 28 to 31 of the Infection Protection Act (IfSG) of July 20, 2000 (Federal Law Gazette I p. 1045), which was last amended by Article 1 of the Act of May 19, 2020 (Federal Law Gazette I p.  1018) has been changed, the following is prescribed:...* The entry conditions for Germany are set by federal law, which state laws may not contradict (including the date one entered Germany).

Comment: @MarkJohnson "The entry conditions for Germany are set by federal law, **which state laws may not contradict**" Exactly, so no matter what the states write on their sites, they can't demand a pre-registration form (which in turn requires an address) for those only transiting without staying overnight at an address. Besides, border checks are exclusively done by the **Bundes**polizei anyway (except in Bavaria where they share the task with the Bayerische Grenzpolizei)

Comment: @Crazydre Yes that is how I see it. But TorEinarJarnbjo remark is justified that maybe not all travel providers are aware of this distinction.

Comment: @MarkJohnson And it doesn't help that TIMATIC doesn't state it. Already written to my IATA contact about it, to help prevent wrongful denied boardings down the line.

Comment: @Crazydre There is also a PDF that can be printed and manually filled out and given to the provider or border control if there is no internet connection to fill out the electronic form. [Merkblatt und Informationen zur digitalen Einreiseanmeldung - Bundesgesundheitsministerium](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/merkblatt-dea.html)

Comment: @MarkJohnson I've seen that one. One could then simply "cross out" fields 16-27.